# Ruby Arrays: select(), collect(), and map()

Tags: ruby, arrays

The syntax for mapping:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]      #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
a.map {|item|"a" == item}     #=> [true, false, false, false] 
a.select {|item|"a" == item}  #=> ["a"]
```

Question how about if I have:

```
 irb(main):105:0> details[1]
 => {:sku=>"507772-B21", :desc=>"HP 1TB 3G SATA 7.2K RPM LFF (3 .", :qty=>"", 
 :qty2=>"1", :price=>"5,204.34 P"}
```

I want to delete every entry which has an empty qty value on this array or select only the ones with some value in it.

I tried:

```
details.map {|item|"" == item}
```

Just returns a lot of false and then when I use the same just change map to select I get:

```
[]
```

Comment: If you look closely, it looks like it's an array of hashes

Comment: @Emily: Very true, I just realized that. The last code sample made me think otherwise, because `:qty` doesn't even appear there.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

It looks like `details` is an array of hashes. So `item` inside of your block will be the whole hash. Therefore, to check the `:qty` key, you'd do something like the following:

```
details.select{ |item| item[:qty] != "" }
```

That will give you all items where the `:qty` key isn't an empty string.

[official select documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 31):

**EDIT:** I just realized you want to filter `details`, which is an array of hashes. In that case you could do

```
details.reject { |item| item[:qty].empty? }
```

---

The inner data structure itself is not an Array, but a Hash. You can also use `select` here, but the block is given the key and value in this case:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {:sku=>"507772-B21", :desc=>"HP 1TB 3G SATA 7.2K RPM LFF (3 .", :qty=>"", :qty2=>"1", :price=>"5,204.34 P"}
irb(main):002:0> h.select { |key, value| !value.empty? }
=> {:sku=>"507772-B21", :desc=>"HP 1TB 3G SATA 7.2K RPM LFF (3 .", 
    :qty2=>"1", :price=>"5,204.34 P"}
```

Or using `reject`, which is the inverse of `select` (excludes all items for which the given condition holds):

```
h.reject { |key, value| value.empty? }
```

Note that this is Ruby 1.9. If you have to maintain compatibility with 1.8, you could do:

```
Hash[h.reject { |key, value| value.empty? }]
```

Comment: @ingalcala: I just realized that my answer is not actually what you need. Please check my edit for how to filter the `details` array itself.

Answer (score 9):

When dealing with a hash `{}`, use both the key and value to the block inside the `||`.

```
details.map {|key,item|"" == item}

=>[false, false, true, false, false]
```